# how to return null values from a dateTime column in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have a query where i am trying to check when a date is specified it should check if a user has checked into a store and checked out of a stored between the given dates.
the checked out column is nullable, if its null it means the user didnt check out as yet

example

Table

```
Id   |  checkedIN                           |  checkedOut
111  | 2022-06-13 18:22:01.4570125 +00:00   | null
111  |2022-06-13 17:59:03.3697131 +00:00    | 2022-06-14 19:36:54.5744837 +00:00
758  |2022-05-14 19:36:54.5744837 +02:00    |2022-06-12 19:36:54.5744837 +00:00
```

so in sql if i do the following

```
select *
from table
where id='111' and '2022/06/14' between cast([checkedIN] as date) and ISNULL(cast([checkedOut] as date),'2022/06/14')
```

i get the correct records back which the output would be

```
    Id   |  checkedIN                           |  checkedOut
    111  | 2022-06-13 18:22:01.4570125 +00:00   | null
    111  |2022-06-13 17:59:03.3697131 +00:00    | 2022-06-14 19:36:54.5744837 +00:00
```

so i want to convert this query to linq.
this is what i have

```
sdate = DateTime.Parse(query.filteredDate.ToString());
Where(x => x.id== query.id && (sdate >= x.checkedIn && sdate <= x.checkedOut))
```

this above where clause outputs only the following

```
Id   |  checkedIN                           |  checkedOut
111  |2022-06-13 17:59:03.3697131 +00:00    | 2022-06-14 19:36:54.5744837 +00:00
```

as you can see its ignoring the record that has checkedOut of null record.
How do i tell my linq where clause to include the null values for that date range?

Comment: You can use `== null` or `!= null`.  Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the checkedOut date is null

```
.Where(x => 
    x.id == query.id && 
    sdate >= x.checkedIn && 
    (x.checkedOut == null || sdate <= x.checkedOut)
)
```